# Making links easier to click on mobile devices, mobile devices help

Tags: mobile, mobile-web, touch-screen, hyperlinks

I designed my website several years ago. I quite like it but have noticed it is not optimal for mobile devices.

http://isometricland.net/homeworld/homeworld.php

I am thinking the text links in the left column of the tables are too narrowly spaced, but spreading them out looks bad. Does anyone have any advice on how to make these links work better on mobile touch screens, or mobile advice in general?

Would it be better if I designed a separate version of my site entirely *just* for mobile devices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hamburger menu for the navigation of

[image]

and on the below links like the facebook, search and donate now.

just like here

[image]

and then put all of your content into the middle using any grid(preferably bootstrap). In the content, you have two and three CTAs put them aligned just after the related data.

e.g. 
in **News**,

paragraph - I ported my Play Balancing Mod to Homeworld Remastered, and am currently in the process of generating a new Ship vs. Ship Odds spreadsheet for HWRM.

*link*

in **Tools**,

paragraph - An HTML form that generates a branching tree of resources that you can then copy and import into HW1. The amount and frequency of branching, as well as the number of intervals between branchings, may be specified.
(The screenshot kind of looks like a pair of antlers.)

IMAGE

*link*

and hence proceeds in the same way.

Comment: I like the hamburger menu suggestion, but for his second question this here might be interesting too:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/mobile-vs-responsive/

Comment: What is a bootstrap? What are CTAs?

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS based framework which is very good and responsive - It used to be called Twitter Bootstrap. CTA is Call to Action(s) and is typically the primary button that triggers the feature, e.g. Save button is a CTA.

Comment: Are you familiar with responsive?

Comment: I read @Big_Chair's link.

Comment: What do I do if each item has multiple links? Such as 'Download', 'Discussion', 'Readme'. Do I space them horizontally or vertically?

Comment: You need to make the tap region bigger around each link using CSS. Typically at least 44 pixels tall. Responsive grid based frameworks like Bootstrap use browser window breakpoints to apply different CSS rules to objects like links. Obviously you get all this for free with Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks @steveD for having my back. In addition to the above comments, Bootstrap will not cost much of your time and if you know this much of html css then it will be plus point if you will learn the grid system as this is the most convenient way of making responsive web app.